# LATEX : save the value of a cell in Tabular

Tags: tables, spreadtab

This question may seem very simple but I didn't find a solution!

I have a table with some values. Among these values, I want to save some of them to re-use them in a table that summarizes few tables.

How can I save the values which are in the cell to be able to re-use them later ?

Thanks a lot !

PS: With `spreadtab`, I cannot customize the columns as I defined them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 % I will re-use the values 5 and 6 later
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  10 & 11 & 12 % I will re-use the values 11 and 12 later
\end{tabular}


%Summary table 
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  5 & 6 \\
  11 & 12
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you put please your complete minimal compilable code?

Comment: Ok, it's done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach could be to save each element to be reused in a variable. In this case, you can easily change the value only at one place.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\newcommand{\myvarA}{5}
\newcommand{\myvarB}{6}
\newcommand{\myvarC}{11}
\newcommand{\myvarD}{12}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & \myvarA & \myvarB % I will re-use the values 5 and 6 later
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  10 & \myvarC & \myvarD % I will re-use the values 11 and 12 later
\end{tabular}


%Summary table 
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \myvarA & \myvarB \\
  \myvarC & \myvarD
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```